# Firebase storage emulator ignored by go admin sdk

Tags: go, firebase-storage, firebase-admin, firebase-tools

I'm trying to setup the storage emulator for my firebase project. I am using the Go admin sdk. However it seems to be ignored despite following the [documented process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage#admin_sdks).

App initialization:

```golang
func App(ctx context.Context) (*firebase.App, error) {
    opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("firebase-service-account.json")
    config := firebase.Config{
        StorageBucket: "<my-project-id>.appspot.com",
    }
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, &config, opt)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error initializing app: %v", err)
    }
    return app, nil
}
```

.env file loaded on startup:

```
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8081"
FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9199"
GCLOUD_PROJECT="my-project-id"
```

I also tried manually setting these by running:
`export FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9199"` and `export GCLOUD_PROJECT="my-project-id"`.

However, when when writing to the default bucket, my blob appears in the actual firestore console for storage, not the storage emulator.

I pulled the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` value from my service account json file, the `project_id` field specifically. Also confirmed that `9199` is the port that storage is running on.

Besides setting those `FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST` and `GCLOUD_PROJECT` am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

The variable name is STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST.

See: https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage

Answer (score 0):

Firebaser Here,

You're correct in that your current setup should have been sufficient. I've filed [an issue in the GO SDK Repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/issues/520) so that this can get addressed.

In the meanwhile the current fix, as @mabg pointed out, is to set the `STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST` variable as well  [Code Sample](https://github.com/abhis3/firebase-go-admin-sdk-mvp/blob/main/hello.go#L35)